# mongoosejs perform query within methods

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoosejs and have custom methods to populate some data during pre save.  Is there a way to query the db, within methods?

For example:

```
UserSchema.methods.createRandom = function(callback) {
    var random = 123;
    this.findOne({random: random}, function(err, doc) { 
    if (!doc) return callback(random);
      this.createRandom(callback);  
    });
}

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) { 
  this.createRandom(function(random) {
     this.random = random;
     next();
  });
}
```

This is basically what I'm trying to acheive, but `this` in methods does not reference the model, it references the object to be saved.   Anyway to access the model for the `findOne()`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit cryptic and I don't know if it's documented anywhere, but I've reliably done this in the past by accessing an instance's model via its `constructor` property:

```
this.constructor.findOne({random: random}, function(err, doc) {
```

Comment: This seems to be a much better answer than mine